# Power Pivot data from C# DataTable

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpivot, powerquery

I apologise if it is a duplicate, but I could not find similar question.

What I try to achieve is to create a Power Pivot model from remote data (JSON). The service requires token authentication, so my initial plan was to build a small extension in C# using VSTO that would ask for credentials, get the token and then create a Power Query (in VBA it would be `ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add` with 'Authorization' token in header) that in turn would be the source for Power Pivot model. However, [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.aspx) does not seem to provide Interop access to "Queries".

As an alternative, I was thinking about querying the data directly in C#, creating DataTable and outputting it into Data Model. But then again, creating Data Model table from C# DataTable does not seem to be possible.

Could you please explain if there is a way to achieve the desired behaviour? I have strong feeling that I am doing something completely wrong.

Comment: You said C#, Data Table and PowerPivot but where Excel fits in these or what is role of Excel as without Excel you can't use PowerPivot? What is working for me is that Excel, a template with a existing connection (which gets data from whatever source and uploads to PowerPivot). This way I can manipulate the connection and PowerPivot objects the way I want it.

Comment: Here is the initial design of the flow: a user creates a new empty excel file, goes to the add-in (written in C# using VSTO) and uses to authorise on the server and make an api call, that returns JSON. This json is then parsed into Excel's DataModel.